# what's the meaning of "all along the perimeter"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In American TV show "The Office" S2E11 "Booze Cruise", the captain of a ship is introducing safety instructions. He says, "the life preservers are located underneath the seats all along the perimeter." 
  What's the meaning of "perimeter" in this context? Does it mean "every single seat on this ship"?

Another question: In another scene of this episode, Michael (the leading role of this TV show who is a regional manager of a paper company) seems unhappy about the truth that he is not the boss of this ship so he says, "In an office, when you are ranking people, manager is higher than captain. On a boat, who knows? It's nebul-ose." What kind of special meanings Michael wants to express by taking the word "nebulose" apart?

Comment: First, "along the perimeter" means "round the edge." Second, it seems to be a word-play on [**nebulous**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nebulous) and perhaps would mean more if I watched the show.

Comment: The "perimeter" means *the outer edge*. In the context of a ship, that might imply there aren't actually any lifebelts underneath any "centrally-positioned" seats. But that seems a bit unlikely, so I expect the scriptwriters simply weren't paying attention. And the (really weak) "pun" in ***who knows / nebul-ose*** is probably just supposed to imply that the speaker is a bit pretentious (but *possibly* doesn't even know how to pronounce ***nebulous***; it's all a bit vague).

Comment: To complicate the mystery, M-W gives "nebulose" as a variant spelling of "nebulous".